# DLL automatically added in build output

Tags: c#

I have a c# solution with a Winform project (project A) and a library poject (project B).

My project B have component DLL reference (copy-local set to FALSE)

When i build only my project B => 0 DLL in output

When i build my project A (Project reference between projects A & B) => i have in build output all component DLL referenced in B and not in A .

If i had the reference in A and set copy locale to false, it not copied.

do I have to reference all the DLLs of my project B in project A ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your library. It should be built to its project folder instead of the project folder of your forms application. You do not have to link all your libraries to your 'Master Project', but VS will decide if the library is needed to build if you did no set it explicitly within the build configuration of your solution.

Comment: my project has a reference (project reference) to my project B, this reference is set to copy local TRUE, otherwise I have an error during execution in VS.
When VS my soluion, i have in my project B output only projectb.dll but in project A output, i have :
- ProjectB.dll => ok
- PorjectA.exe => Ok
- Some DLLs referenced in projectB => i don't want it

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the DLL Referencing: To add onto greg-e's answer; if you want to add your DLL to your "master project", build
the project to its original project (as he said) and then reference it from the build location? It will show up in the "master" build if you reference and use the functions then it will appear in the "master" build.

Solution to the numerous References: If you're making your library with references to other
DLL/APIs, it becomes dependent on that file to make it function. They will be included in the Project B output so B.DLL can function. Simply, you would need to copy the other DLL files to another location and call them from there if you are intent on using it with only A.exe and B.DLL. Otherwise you'll have to put up with it.

If I made a mistake, do reply.